# The str_ireplace and preg_replace attemt?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace a string from an original text. ( `zinc` --> `zn` )

Example: `'zinc zinc zinc zinc3 !zinc zincmatic #zinc zinc9 Zinc @zinc@'`

Want: `'zn zn zn zinc3 !zn zincmatic #zinc zinc9 zn @zinc@'`

**The str_ireplace attempt:**

```
$text = 'zinc zinc zinc zinc3 !zinc zincmatic #zinc zinc9 Zinc @zinc@';
$word = 'zinc';
$attr = 'zn';

// cant str_ireplace now as zincmatic will turn into znmatic and #zinc will turn into #zn
$text = ' '.$text.' '; 
$word = ' '.$zinc.' ';

// will try now
$result = str_ireplace($word, $attr, $word);
echo trim($result);
```

Prints `zn zinc zn zinc3 !zinc zincmatic #zinc zinc9 zn @zinc@`. Still have problems as `!zinc` and second `zinc` remains due to space problems..

**The preg_replace attempt:**

```
$text = 'zinc zinc zinc zinc3 !zinc zincmatic #zinc zinc9 zinc';
$word = 'zinc';
$attr = 'zn';
$result = preg_replace("/\b($word)\b/i",$attr,$text);
echo $result;
```

Prints `zn zn zn zinc3 !zn zincmatic #zn zinc9 zn @zn@`
almost got what i want: seems that zinc will turn into `zn` even if there is some special char near like `!zinc` or `#zinc` but not if there is a number `zinc9` or text like `zincmatic`

I just want to put a rule here so that `#zinc` keeps `#zinc`, `@zinc@` keeps `@zinc@` and `!zinc` turns to `!zn`

Is there a way to add some exceptions to special chars if zinc is near one of them ( ie : `#zinc`, `zinc#`, `zinc@`, `@zinc`)

The chars I want to be an execptions are `#`, `&`, `@`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define such exceptions with negative [assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They behave similar to `\b` and can in fact be used in conjunction.

In your case you want `(?<![#&@])` to probe the preceding character, and `(?![#&@])` to test the following character.

```
= preg_replace("/(?<![#&@])\b($word)\b(?![#&@])/i",$attr,$text);
```